# voltage to current Module

Tags: voltage, current

I want to output signal in current form (4ma - 20mA) from arduino. I plan to use DAC to get high resolution analog signal 0-5V, but how to get convert if from Voltage form to Current form is not clear jet to me. Please suggest me how to achieve it. So some simple but still stable, good DIY circuits or some relativly cheap products (shields,...)

Thank you.

Damir

Comment: According to the description it works with continuous input between 0 to 2.5V, and then jumping by discrete levels.

Comment: Connecting VOUT to ground is not a usual thing, but without a real datasheet, it's hard to know anything about how you're supposed to use this thing.

Comment: It may be that the 9 volt battery can not supply enough current?

Comment: Datasheet for the pressure regulator, please. Add the link **into your original question** (where it belongs) and not in the comments.

Comment: @Dado87: (1) You've removed the reference to the pressure regulator from your question. This makes my answer look totally irrelevant. (2) "_Please suggest me how to achieve it._" The obvious answer to this will be a voltage to 4-20mA converter. (3) "_... or some relativly cheap products (shields,...)_" is a blatant shopping question and will have your post closed. Can you fix all three issues, please?

Answer (score 2):

You've missed something crucial: the device needs a nominal 24 V DC to power it. The 4-20 mA signal is just a *control* signal.

[image]

*Figure 1. MPPE technical data. Note 18 ... 30 V DC supply.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The 8-pin connector pinout.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM5ACl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. A likely connection diagram.*

You haven't (for some reason) posted a link for the 4-20mA module so we don't know whether it is current sourcing or current sinking. The Festo documentation is vague too but I suspect it's current sinking so you have to drive 4 - 20 mA *into* the setpoint pin. That means your driver has to *source* that current. You may need to call Festo's tech support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

My Voltage to Current module is like that one:
http://www.ebay.de/itm/Voltage-to-Current-0-5V-to-4-20mA-Conversion-Module-for-Arduino-/262495219570?hash=item3d1def2f72
Yes I know that device needs 24V. But for now I want to ensure that I can provide current signal 4-20mA. First I need to "calibrate" my modul (for it there are two pots there)...but at the moment I cant see that current on my ampmeter.

Comment: All that information needs to be in the question and not in the comments. There is no datasheet on that link. I can't help without one.

Comment: I cannot post more then 2 links in question. Thats just cheap modul from ebay...I tought that that is common part for converting Voltage to Current. I cant find datasheet :(